# How to peek next and prev elements in a boost set<cpp_int>

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to store boost integers cpp_int in an **ordered** set and check for next and prev elements using below code:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
using boost::unordered_set;
using namespace std;

int main() {

        set<mp::cpp_int> st;
        set<mp::cpp_int>::iterator it, it1, it2;
        //pair<set<mp::cpp_int>::iterator,bool> res;
        boost::tuples::tuple<set<mp::cpp_int>::iterator, bool> tp;

        int i = 0, temp;
        while(i<10){

            cin>>temp;

            tp = st.insert(temp);
            it = get<0>(tp);
            it1 = prev(it);
            it2 = next(it);
            cout<<*it1<<endl;
            //cout<<*it2<<endl;

            i++;
        }

    return 0; 
}
```

However, the above code does not work as expected and crashes after couple of inputs. One such crashing sequence of inputs is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
0
```

What is the proper way of using set and iterators when using boost?

Comment: You need to check that `it1` and `it2` are valid before dereferencing them.

Comment: I am inserting an element before getting it1 and it2. So, I should always have a valid iterator.

Comment: `it` should always be valid, but `it1` and `it2` have no guarantee to be valid - What is the previous element of the first element in a set with a single element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check that there is a previous / next element before dereferencing the `it1` and `it2`, e.g.:

```
std::set<mp::cpp_int> s;

for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i){

    std::cin >> temp;

    auto p = s.insert(temp);
    if (p.second) { // insertion succeed

        auto it = p.first;

        std::cout << "Inserted: " << *it << '\n';

        if (it != s.begin()) { // not the first, there is a previous element
            auto it1 = std::prev(it);
            std::cout << "Previous: " << *it1 << '\n';
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Previous: None\n";
        }

        auto it2 = std::next(it);
        if (it2 != s.end()) { // there is a next element
            std::cout << "Next: " << *it2 << '\n';
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Next: None\n";
        }
    }

}
```

Also, if you want to find the previous and next elements of an existing element, you should use `std::set::find`, not `std::set::insert`:

```
 auto it = s.find(temp);
 if (it != s.end()) {
     // Same code as above.
 }
```

Comment: I think I got my mistake. Thanks. But the c++ reference (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/) says that if I try to insert and element, it would give me an iterator to the existing element if insertion fails. So I tried to use it.

Comment: @user3243499 Yes, but that's clearly misleading if someone read your code afterwards, plus `insert` will insert a new element, while `std::find` does not modify the `set`, which is probably what you want when you are looking for previous / next.